# Return only 3 values from a function on one page and all the values on the other page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have this function which performs some calculations and returns 6 values in an object.
But on page A, I only want it to calculate and return the first 3 values. On page B, I want it to return all the values.

I want to avoid using the string comparison and wanted to make use of currying.

The values being calculated are dependent on each other. For example, `value3` uses `value2` to calculate. `value4` uses `value1` to calculate.

```
export const transformMeasurementStats = (data: Data[]) => {
const result = data.map((item) => {
    if (item.measurementSamples) {
        
        //All these calculations are dependent on one another. 
        // e.g. value3 uses value2 to calculate and so on.
        
        const value1 = //some calculation
        const value2 = //some calculation
        const value3 = //some calculation
        const value4 = //some calculation
        const value5 = //some calculation
        const value6 = //some calculation


        return { value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6};
    }
});

return result;
```

};

Comment: How does the function determine if it is executed in Page A or Page B?

Comment: I can add another argument to the function for the page name and perform an if check. But that is what I want to avoid doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure you want to implement it using currying, below could be one way of making it work:

```
const transformMeasurementStats = (num) => (data) => {
  const result = data.map((item) => {
    if (item.measurementSamples) {
      //All these calculations are dependent on one another.
      // e.g. value3 uses value2 to calculate and so on.

      const value1 = "1";
      const value2 = "2";
      const value3 = "3";
      const value4 = "4";
      const value5 = "5";
      const value6 = "6";

      return num === 3
        ? { value1, value2, value3 }
        : { value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6 };
    }
  });
  return result;
};
const data = [{ measurementSamples: true }];

console.log(transformMeasurementStats(3)(data));
console.log(transformMeasurementStats()(data));
```

Dynamically returning a certain number of values (or all, if no value of `num` provided):

Could use Map instead of array if keys matter.

```
const transformMeasurementStats = (num) => (data) => {
  const result = data.map((item) => {
    if (item.measurementSamples) {
      //All these calculations are dependent on one another.
      // e.g. value3 uses value2 to calculate and so on.

      const values = [];
      values[0] = "1";
      values[1] = "2";
      values[2] = "3";
      values[3] = "4";
      values[4] = "5";
      values[5] = "6";

      const resultValues = {};
      num = num ? num : values.length - 1;
      for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
        resultValues[`value${i}`] = values[i];
      }
      return resultValues;
    }
  });
  return result;
};

const data = [{ measurementSamples: true }];

// return all 6 values
console.log(transformMeasurementStats()(data));
// return
const getFirst3Values = transformMeasurementStats(3);
console.log(getFirst3Values(data));
```

Hope it helps.